# Apache2 whith mod_wsgi python3 'TypeError:' and return error 500

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, apache2, mod-wsgi

My 'controller.py' script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

def application(environ, start_response):
    # the ouput string to respuesta var
    respuesta = "<p>Página web construida con <strong>Python!!!</strong></p>"
    # generating the response OK
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')])
    return respuesta
```

In 'error.log':

> [Mon Mar 13 12:36:32.656669 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28767:tid
>   139926041507584] [client 127.0.0.1:56382] mod_wsgi (pid=28767):
>   Exception occurred processing WSGI script
>   '/var/www/python/app/controller.py'. [Mon Mar 13 12:36:32.656761 2017]
>
> [wsgi:error] [pid 28767:tid 139926041507584] [client 127.0.0.1:56382]
>   TypeError: sequence of byte string values expected, value of type str
>   found ubuntu@ip-*-*-*-*:/var/www/python/logs$  TypeError:
>   sequence of byte string values expected, value of type str found

I've read [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937508/mod-wsgi-with-python-3-4-get-an-error-sequence-of-byte-string-values-expected-v) but the answer doesn't works.

my site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName app.salvaj.es
    ServerAdmin salvajgb@salvaj.es
    DocumentRoot /var/www/python/static
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/python/app/controller.py

    ErrorLog /var/www/python/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/python/logs/access.log combined

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/python/static>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have yu installed  the mod-wsgi? sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-wsgi

Comment: @PierangeloOrizio yes, and enabled with `sudo a2enmod wsgi`

Comment: Can you post the virtual host configuration? domain.conf

Comment: @PierangeloOrizio done! site.conf added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing two things wrong.

The first is that the response must be an iterable over bytes, not Unicode.

The second is that you are returning a string, rather than a list of strings. The latter makes your code very inefficient as single character at a time is being sent back.

Use:

```
return [respuesta.encode('UTF-8')]
```

Better still, do not write WSGI applications from scratch yourself, use a web framework like Flask as it handles all these sorts of details for you.

Comment: that works!  Yes, i'll use Flask, but first at all I tried to learn how do it without a framework.

Comment: You are better off starting with Flask and only if there is a need then learn about raw WSGI. There are too many gotchas in raw WSGI and it is not a good place to start if learning.